# Creating a Network Dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, network-analyst, network-dataset

I need some basic instructions on how to create a network dataset in ArcMap 10.1. I do realize there are esri tutorials out there but I'm having difficulty understanding everything. I'm just looking for a little help to get started.

What I want to do: perform Network Analysis on a potential new hospital site - I want to see how this new site will compare to an existing hospital location in terms of how many people it covers, accessibility, etc.

So first I need to create a Network dataset. I currently have streets and public transit route shapefiles, and I created 2 polygon features for the old and the new hospital location. What else do I need? Where do I go from here?

Comment: Have you *done* the tutorials? The [first exercise](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00470000005t000000) is all about creating a NDS and it's fairly explicit. The second covers multi-modal, addressing your public transit. Exercise 5 is the Service Area solver, which is one way to do what you're looking at. You'll likely want the locations as points, not polygons, but they're not actually part of the network. And if looking at population served you'll need population data in some form eventually. Your question is a bit broad for the GIS.SE format.

Answer (score 2):

First go through my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/104262/14435. This will let you understand how to create a network dataset. Go though an Esri KB exercise - I recommend this to anyone who starts working with NA. It won't take much time but will give you all the basics you need to create a network dataset on your own (with your own data). Ask more questions on this site if you encounter problems when building a ND.

[HowTo:  Prepare data for use with the Network Analyst extension](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32890)

Then look which kind of network analysis you would need to perform. From what you desribe, it looks like you need [Service area analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Service_area_analysis/004700000048000000/). Make your hospitals points and load them as facilities. Go through the tutorial (on service areas part):

[Exercise 5: Calculating service areas and creating an OD cost matrix](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Exercise_5_Calculating_service_areas_and_creating_an_OD_cost_matrix/004700000060000000/)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the link -
very detail solution with basics
https://youtu.be/K1Z3AGOnWrc

Comment: It is better to provide details, because links often become invalid which makes the answer worthless. You might also want to disclose that you created the video.