# How to compute Travelling Salesman Problem by ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I'm newbie in geography. I have a number of x-y coordinates in a text file. I want to compute the shortest path going through these points in ArcGIS. I can load my data points in ArcGIS, but network analyst options are disabled. Would you please help me how to do the computation?

Comment: Why negative point? Please let me know the reason.

Comment: I have noticed that down voting is the way of saying 'hello to newbie' in SE, I have sterted with the same warm welcome.  it is been taken off, lucky you ;)

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use [Network Analyst extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//004700000001000000). It is a separate extension you would need to buy, it can be installed with the ArcGIS for Desktop installation, but to use it you need to buy a license.

1. [Enable](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#/Configuring_the_Network_Analyst_environment/004700000005000000/) extension in ArcMap.
2. [Obtain / prepare](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104257/how-to-format-street-network-data-for-network-analysis/104262#104262) network dataset.
3. Use [Route layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#/Route_analysis/004700000045000000/) with Reorder Stops To Find Optimal Route option.

> By default, a route traverses stops in the order you define. However,
>   you can possibly shorten the route further by letting Network Analyst
>   find the best order. It will account for a variety of variables, such
>   as time windows. Another option is to preserve the origin and
>   destination while allowing Network Analyst to reorder the intermediary
>   stops.
>
> When you check this property, the route analysis changes from a
>   shortest-path problem to a traveling salesperson problem (TSP).

Comment: Do you have to pay for Network Analyst or does it come out-of-the-box with every ArcGIS package? Did you purchase the Network Analyst extension @remo?

Comment: @John, updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I wasn't sure myself - which is why I asked the question =) Which is the point of GIS.SE! Thanks for verifying.

Comment: Yes, I have a full access to ArcGIS in my university. I can show the points on the world map in ArcMAP, but all options in Network Analyst are disabled there. I asked a professor, and he said me you have only points, but you must define routes! I am not sure how to define them , however it must be easy to insert them since there is a straight line connecting each pair using GEOM distance metric.