# Turn point data into line while keeping order in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, travelling-salesman

I have a point dataset (ArcGIS Pro) with around 700 points (Some points are in the same place), and I need to do a route that starts at any point and goes thru all the points, without going back to points that were previously passed thru

I've tried doing "Point to Line" but I get "Spider webs" going back and forth, with no real order. I've done some investigation and it seems that I have to identify the order of the line. Is there any way of giving each point location a number in order to make the line pass thru all of them without manually giving one id to each one?

Here's an image

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a *Travelling Salseman Problem* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem there's a related question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162799/how-to-compute-travelling-salesman-problem-by-arcgis though I can't find any info for ArcGIS Pro network analyst.

Comment: Do you have a Network Analyst license?

Comment: Yes, I am almost certain that I have a network analyst license. I recall using the toolbox previously on other projects. By the way, I've also tried to do network and route analysis, but the processing fails due to having more than 150 "stops".

Comment: If you have 3d Analyst you can create a TIN https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000001v000000 which will generate triangles for all your input points and then drop the TIN to line https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q900000098000000 which you can  then turn into a network - your solution will be among the facets of the TIN which will join all the points with their nearest group of points.

Comment: Too many stops for salesman problem. You can do itrations. Convex hull of all, exclude points,  next convex hull etc. Smooth connection between rings a bit challenging

Comment: @FelixIP how many stops would be acceptable for a salesman problem? I understand that the processing required increases exponentially with the count of stops; I've not done one of these so am a little curious just in case one of these problems *does* come my way in the future.

Comment: Any solution with decent number of stops is only approximate. Exact solution for small number near 100(? Read somewhere) is too much for all computers in the world. Unless it was about Steiner tree:(