# Why there is no "create network dataset" option when I right click my shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I wanted to use Network Analyst toolbox to do a vehicle routing problem in ArcGIS. When I right click the related shapefile which includes links of the network, there is no "create network dataset" option there. I created a network before but that was not the one I wanted to use. Now that I want to create a new network dataset, it does not let me do that. when I chooses "a new vehicle routing problem" from Network Analyst toolbar, it seems that it is using the information from the previous network dataset that I created. I am confused. I wonder if I should remove the previous network dataset so it let me create new network datasets. I even removed the previous network dataset but it seems that the toolbox is still considering that.

Comment: A network dataset requires a geodatabase (multiple cooperative tables)

Comment: well I am having the problem with a geodatabase as well.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to focus on your file geodatabase, since a network dataset shapefile is a non sequitur.  Also needed: Whether the FGDB is local or networked (this sounds like a corrupted networked FGDB)

Comment: Please keep in mind that it is *possible* to create a network dataset from shapefile. Source: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/what-is-a-network-dataset.htm

Answer (score 3):

A Network Dataset needs to be created in a **Feature Dataset** within a Geodatabase.  Right-click on the Feature Dataset that contains your network features, and you'll be given the option to create a new Network Dataset

[image]

You can not create a Network Dataset directly at the base level of the geodatabase.  This may be why you don't get the option when you right-click within the geodatabase.  Move your network feature classes into your feature dataset (spatial reference will need to match), and create the Network from there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems as @bahar has added a created network dataset into ArcMap map and tries to create a network analyst layer, because he said:

> when I chooses "a new vehicle routing problem" from Network Analyst
>   toolbar,

Sometimes when removing an old ND and adding a new one, especially when they have the same name, some cache can be left. It's best to create a new map document and add the new ND there.

Also keep in mind that the same polyline shapefile cannot participate in multiple network datasets. So, if you have used your shapefile to build a ND, it will be impossible to re-use it for building another one.

If you are just starting with network analysis, I strongly recommend reviewing the Help pages [Designing the network dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/designing-the-network-dataset.htm) and [GIS.SE answer on Network Analysis with ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/104262/14435).