# Working with NDS files in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I'm working on a final project for class and the professor created a network dataset that's held in a .ND folder. The folder holds six NDS files.

How do I work with these files in ArcGIS to perform network analysis?

Comment: Welcome to SE, please read our [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Please edit your question with what you've tried. Are you trying to open the file in Arc Map?

Answer (score 2):

First, this means that you've got an ArcGIS Network Dataset (further ND) stored in a file folder and it is based on a shapefile which is supposed to be used along with the ND. When creating an ND inside a file geodatabase, you will get a bunch of other files. The ND depends on its source polyline shapefile, so be sure not to rename it or move it otherwise the ND will stop working.

Second, you are supposed to be using the ArcGIS Desktop software to interact with the network dataset because it's a binary item. Start ArcMap, [enable Network Analyst extension](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/configuring-the-network-analyst-extension.htm) (provided you have it installed and licensed) and navigate to the network dataset folder. You should be able to see the ND along with the source shapefile it's based on and junctions if there are connectivity rules established.

This is how the network dataset is drawn in ArcMap:

[image]

In Windows File explorer, this is how the folder `netan` looks like:

[image]

To get started with Network Analyst, look at this answer:

[Formatting street network data for ArcGIS Network Analyst?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104257/formatting-street-network-data-for-arcgis-network-analyst)

To learn about network analysis, refer to the Esri Help page: [Network analysis workflow](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/network-analysis-workflow.htm)